# How to set the database in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql, data-binding

I have a database at location xmachina\sqlexpress named News, News has a table NewsTable.  How do I tell ASP to look at News database?  Is it part of the SelectCommand?  Or a webconfig variable?

Right now I get a [SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'NewsTable'.]

web.config

```
<add name="NewsTableConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=XMACHINA\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Default.aspx

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NewsTableConnectionString %>"
       ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NewsTableConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
       SelectCommand="SELECT [NewsHeadline] FROM [NewsTable]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed this "Initial Catalog" attribute

```
<add name="NewsTableConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=XMACHINA\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=News" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 2):

use this in your connection string setting in your web.config

> Database=News;

See the following site for in depth details: [link text](http://www.connectionstrings.com)